# Why -ss is taking so long?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have the code below and I noticed that when there's the **-ss** parameter the compilation takes longer, is this expected? There's some way to work it around?

```
-i "bg.png" 
-i "media.mp4" 
-i "assets.png" 
-ss 0:00:01.189000 
-filter_complex "
    [1:v]scale=720.0:-2[mainMedia];
    [0:v][mainMedia]overlay=x=(W-w)/2:y=(H-h)/2[mix1];
    [2:v]scale=720.0:-2[widgets];
    [mix1][widgets]overlay[outfile]
    " 
-framerate 30 
-b:v 1.0k 
-frames:v 1 
-s 576x1024 
-crf 21 
-preset medium 
-map [outfile]
```

Comment: Some comments unrelated to the main question. `-framerate 30` is not an output option: it is an input option for the [image demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-1). `-b:v` and `-crf` are mutually exclusive methods of rate control, so one of them is being ignored. Choose one but not both. I prefer using the scale filter instead of `-s` so all of the filtering can occur in the filtergraph and it provides more control of when the scaling occurs (and provides more scaling options).

Comment: How can I setup the output frame rate?

Comment: `-r` option or [fps filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#fps).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this expected?

Yes. [When using `-ss` after `-i` (output seeking)](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Seeking):

> [I]nput will be decoded (and discarded) until it reaches the position given by `-ss`. This will be done **very slowly**, frame by frame.

> Is there some way to work around it?

Perhaps, but you may not want to. The rest of the FFmpeg Trac entry above goes on to say:

> As of FFmpeg 2.1, the main advantage [of output seeking] is that when applying filters to the output stream, the timestamps aren't reset prior to filtering (i.e. when ​burning subtitles into a video, you don't need to modify the subtitle timestamps)[.]

If this isn't a concern, you can try input seeking (placing `-ss` at the very start of the command, before any relevant `-i` options), which should be much faster.

Comment: I gonna test and let you know

Comment: @MarcoA.Braghim Because the other inputs are images you will only need `-ss` before `media.mp4`.